# how can i set a tabindex for jquery tabs in a simple ajax post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, struts2

i'm a newbie to ajax and jquery

im loading jquery tabs using a function

```
$(function() {

     $("#tabs").tabs({active: '<s:property value="tabIndex" />'});

});
```

// this tab index I set from backend

and my ajax post function is something like

```js
function loadTabs() {
  var selectId = document.getElementById("sId").value;
  $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "loadTabsForPage.action?pageName=" + selectId,
    cache: false,
    data: {},
    success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {

      alert(data);
      if (data != null) {
        $('#ajaxDiv').html(data);

      }
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      alert('Error while request..' + textStatus + "   " + errorThrown);
    }
  });

}
```

the above both functions will be in my javascript. The jsp content will be something like:

```html
<table>

  <tr>
    <td align="left">Select Page:
      <s:select list="pageList" listKey="pageKey" listValue="pageValue" name="pageName" id="selectedField" headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select Page" onchange="loadTabs();" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

the jsp contents after performing onchange from my jsp ajax post will be triggered and contents will be loaded as below

```html
<div id="ajaxDiv">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><s:property value="tabLabel" />
      </td>

      <td style="text-align: center;"><s:property value="orderLabel" />
      </td>

      <td style="text-align: center;"><s:property value="activeLabel" />
      </td>

      <td style="text-align: center;"><s:property value="defaultLabel" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  // underneath this i display my ajax tabs

  <s:if test="tabsList != null">
    <div id="tabs">
      <ul>
        <s:iterator value="tabsList" status="tabLoopCounter">

          <li>
            <a id="<s:property value='tabPkey' />TabId" href="#<s:property value='tabPkey' />DivId">
              <s:property value="tabName" />
            </a>
          </li>


        </s:iterator>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </s:if>
</div>
```

So with this scenario the table contents are loaded perfectly but im unable to load the tabs. I can see only hyperlinks. 
is it possible to set an index inside post method of ajax or can i publish two divs in a post method
can i get any solution for this

Comment: @AleksandrM : do you mean whether the call $("#tabs").tabs... should be made in ajax post after $('#ajaxDiv').html(data);
or writing the  $("#tabs").tabs... function underneath the loadTabs(). I have tried both its not working

Comment: In the success handler after you have set html. Check console for errors.

Comment: @AleksandrM : thanx.. i have used ajaxComplete to handle that after the Success handler..its working now